# Determine the number of runs of a specified length

Tags: r

I have the following vector, `data`.

```
data <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0)
```

When the number 1 occurs at least 3 times in a row, I'd like to count it as 1.
So the required output for the above would be 2.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `rle()`

```
with(rle(data), sum(lengths >= 3 & values == 1))
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
sum(table(rleid(data),data)[,2]>=3)
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
stri_count(paste(data, collapse=''), regex='1{3,}')
#[1] 2
```

`stringr` does the job but seems to be slower:

```
library(stringr)
str_count(paste(data, collapse=''), '1{3,}')
#[1] 2
```

You can also try this base `R` approach:

```
length(strsplit(gsub('1{3,}', 'a', paste(data, collapse='')), 'a')[[1]]) - 1
#[1] 2
```