# Recognising specific occurrences across columns to create a new variable

Tags: r, function, if-statement, sum

I have a data set that looks like the following

```
year  sh1  sh2  sh3  sh4  sh5
2011   0    1    1    0    0
2012   1    1    0    1    1
2013   0    0    0    0    0
2014   1    1    0    0    0
2015   1    1    1    1    1
```

I'm looking to create a new column that recognises when the number `1` appears in two or more consecutive columns between `sh1` and `sh5`. If this pattern is recognised, it needs to sum up how many times the pattern occurs.

The output I'm after should look something like this:

```
year  sh1  sh2  sh3  sh4  sh5  newVariable
2011   0    1    1    0    0        1
2012   1    1    0    1    1        2
2013   0    0    0    0    0        0
2014   1    1    0    0    0        1
2015   1    1    1    1    1        1
```

Any help would be fantastic.

Thank you

Comment: I upvoted because you did a great example with your data covering "all" possible cases!

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162061/determine-the-number-of-runs-of-a-specified-length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
library(magrittr)
df1$newVariable <-
df1[,-1] %>% apply(1,paste0,collapse="") %>% stringr::str_count("^11|011")

#  year sh1 sh2 sh3 sh4 sh5 newVariable
#1 2011   0   1   1   0   0           1
#2 2012   1   1   0   1   1           2
#3 2013   0   0   0   0   0           0
#4 2014   1   1   0   0   0           1
#5 2015   1   1   1   1   1           1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic case for `rle` function.

```
apply(df[-1], 1, function(i){r1 <- rle(i); sum(r1$lengths[r1$values == 1] >= 2)})
#[1] 1 2 0 1 1
```

Comment: always forget how powerful and general `rle` is.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to `paste` with `do.call` and then count the number of consecutive 1s with a regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
df$new_variable <-  str_count(do.call(paste0, df1[-1]), "(?<=1)1+")
df$new_variable
#[1] 1 2 0 1 1
```